# PHP file not executing Python file from webserver

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm currently working on a project with multiple raspberry's which are all controlled by a main panel on a webpage.
The idea is that if I press a button on the webpage it runs a Python script on the pi which is connected to that certain button.
It works fine, except for one pi.

I used the same code as the other pis but it won't work for some reason.
Could anyone help me out?

PHP file:

```
<?php
system("python /home/pi/Desktop/controllers/slaap-all-off.py");
?>
```

JS code connected to the button calling the php file in the background:

```
$('#dosometing').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://webserverip/dosomething.php'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

if I run the php file on the raspberry it self it will give a reaction, however if I open the file in a webpage it won't do anything.

I think it is somewhere in the permission settings of my pi.

Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the web server running the PHP when you use a webpage have permission to run `sudo`?   Is `python` in the web server's path?

Comment: @CXJ the webserver does run the PHP, i've added a hello world quote and it does display it in the webpage. the webserver is running local on the pi it self so it should be able to reach python

Comment: Why does the python require sudo privileges? What is it doing? And normally if you execute the sudo command you are then required to enter your password, which clearly your code cannot do. Also it's fairly unlikely that the account under which the webserver runs (and therefore under which the PHP is executed when it's called from a web request) will have any sudo privileges at all. That would be a pretty bad idea from a security point of view